# SAS INTNX function

Tags: date, sas

I have a question about `INTNX` function:

```
data have;
date = '11Mar2016'd;
DO tenuremonth = 0 to 12;
    Emth=INTNX('Month', date, tenuremonth); 
    Mthstart=Emth-1;  
    Mthend=INTNX('Month',Emth, 1)-1;
end;

format emth date mth: date9.;

run;
```

My question is:
I know `Mthend` is the last day of month. However, I don't know the difference between `Mthstart` and `Mthend`.
ex. When `tenuremonth` = 1
`Emth` should be equal to `01Apr2016`, and `Mthend` is equal to `31Mar2016`.
It seems that `Mthstart` is the same as `Mthend`. But, they are different actually.
Can anyone explain it?
Appreciate.

Comment: Are you asking what the code is doing or are you trying to accomplish something that isn't working the way you expect? You should look up the fourth parameter for the INTNX function which would solve this question and avoid these issues.

Comment: @Reeza i want to know the result `Mthstart` & `Mthend`, I think they are the same but actually different. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you're missing an explicit `output` statement inside the `do` loop in order to output every iteration of the loop.  I assume this is just a typo as you refer to the value from tenuremonth=1 in your question.

The `intnx` function is working as I would expect, based on your code, maybe you're not fully understanding what it is doing.

As @Reeza mentions, there is a 4th (optional) parameter for `intx` that enables you to return a date at different times in the month, beginning, mid, end and the same as the input date.  If nothing is specified then it defaults to the beginning.

Emth will therefore always returns the 1st of the month, so for tenuremonth=0 this will be 01MAR2016.

Mthstart just takes Emth and subtracts 1 day from it, so will return 29FEB2016.

Mthend takes Emth, advances it by 1 month, then subtracts 1 day, so will retun 31MAR2016.

An easier way to get the month end is to add `end` to `intnx`, like this

```
Mthend=INTNX('Month',date, tenuremonth, 'end');
```

Comment: Definitely agree with the last part.  Probably this is code written originally before the start/end options were added (9.2 I think), or by someone who didn't know about the (sort of) recent addition.

Comment: @Joe it was actually introduced in 9.1 (2004), so it's been around a while now!

Comment: @Robert I'm with him. Anything that's happened this century is recent by my book